# PHP | После создания сессии не переносятся её переменные на другую страницу (localhost openserver)

Tags: php

На другую страницу куки переносятся, а при обращении к массиву $_SESSION пишет, что его не существует.
Код первой страницы

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$isValid=false;
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $_SESSION["user"]=$login;
    $_SESSION["pwd"]=$login;
    if($login=="guest" && $pwd=="guest")
    {
        header("Location: panel.php");
        $isValid=true;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form class="log_form" method="POST">
        <span><b>Вход в систему</b></span><br>
        <span><b>Логин</b></span>
        <input type="text" name="login" style="margin: 5px" />
        <br>
        <span><b>Пароль</b></span>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" style="margin: 5px" /><br>
        <button>Войти</button>
        <?php
        if (!$isValid) 
        {
            echo "<br>Логин или пароль введены
             неправильно!<br><a href='registration.php'>Пройти регистрацию</a>";
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код второй страницы:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    /////////////////////
    if(!empty($_SESSION["user"]))
    {
    $fn = $_POST["first_name"];
    $ln = $_POST["last_name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $user = $_POST["login"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $pwdconf = $_POST["pwd_confirm"];
    if (trim($fn, " ") == "") {
        $err .= "Некорректное имя<br>";
    }
    if (trim($ln, " ") == "") {
        $err .= "Некорректная фамилия<br>";
    }
    if ($age <= 0) {
        $err .= "Некорректный возраст<br>";
    }
    if (strlen($email) <= 1 || strpos($email, "@") == -1) {
        $err .= "Некорректный почтовый адрес<br>";
    }
    if(strlen($user)<=4)
    {
        $err .= "Некорректный логин<br>";
    }
    if ($pwd != $pwdconf) {
        $err .= "Пароли должны быть одинаковыми<br>";
    }
    if (strlen(trim($pwd, " ")) <= 4) {
        $err .= "Пароль должен быть больше 4-х символов<br>";
    }
    if ($err == "") {
        $_SESSION["user"]=$login;
        $_SESSION["pwd"]=$pwd;
        $_SESSION["fn"]=$fn;
        $_SESSION["ln"]=$ln;
        $_SESSION["age"]=$age;
        $_SESSION["emai"]=$email;
        header("Location: panel.php");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form class="reg_form" method="POST">
        <h2>Регистрация пользователя</h2>
        <?php
            if(!empty($err) && $err!="")
            {
                echo "<b>".$err."</b><br>";
            }
        ?>
        <span>Имя</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
        <br>
        <span>Фамилия</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
        <br>
        <span>Возраст</span>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="age" />
        <br>
        <span>E-mail</span>
        <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" />
        <br>
        <span>Логин</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="login" />
        <br>
        <span>Пароль</span>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" />
        <br>
        <span>Повторите пароль</span>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd_confirm" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" />

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Разве на второй странице `session_start();` не нужен?

Comment: Похоже нет. После перезагрузки ПК резко заработало. Не понимаю правда, как перезагрузка могла исправить это. Теперь переменные доступны на второй странице